# Is there a nil value I can use for bytes in Go?

Tags: go

I'm implementing a tree in Go. My TreeNode struct looks like this:

```
type TreeNode struct {
    payload byte
    parent *TreeNode
    children map[byte]*TreeNode
}
```

In my implementation, the root node of the tree is a special node that has no payload. Otherwise the payload is always a single lower-case letter from the English alphabet. So my tree initialization function looks like this:

```
func createEmptyTree(fileName string) *TreeNode{
    return &TreeNode{
        nil,           // Line #180
        nil,
        false,
        map[byte]*TreeNode{},
    }
}
```

When I compile it though, I get the following error: `./main.go:180:9: cannot use nil as type byte in field value`

So it seems I cannot use `nil` for a byte variable. Is there something else I could use in this situation? I could easily use `'0'` or other non alphabetic character. But it seems hacky. What should I do?

Answer (score 16):

`byte` is a [numeric type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types), actually an alias for `uint8`.

That means it has default [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of 0.

Answer (score 4):

For idiomatic Go, write your function as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type TreeNode struct {
    payload  byte
    parent   *TreeNode
    children map[byte]*TreeNode
}

func createEmptyTree(fileName string) *TreeNode {
    return &TreeNode{
        children: map[byte]*TreeNode{},
    }
}

func main() {
    tree := createEmptyTree("fiename")
    fmt.Println(tree)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/v6DJCnpN6Ys

Output:

```
&{0 <nil> map[]}
```

The `payload` value for an empty tree is integer zero (`0`), the zero-value for the integer type `byte`. Zero is not a single lower-case letter value from the English alphabet.

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [The zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)
>
> When storage is allocated for a variable, either through a declaration
>   or a call of new, or when a new value is created, either through a
>   composite literal or a call of make, and no explicit initialization is
>   provided, the variable or value is given a default value. Each element
>   of such a variable or value is set to the zero value for its type:
>   false for booleans, 0 for numeric types, "" for strings, and nil for
>   pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps.

Answer (score 0):

Every type in golang has a zero value. In the case of `byte` that is the null byte.

It's entirely possible to just use the null byte as a magical zero payload at the root.

Comment: You have the zero value confused with a byte-slice.
The zero value for a slice is `nil`. For a `byte`, which is an alias for `uint8`, its `0`.